# Should we have both [gog-galaxy-2.0] and [gog-galaxy]?

Tags: discussion, tag-synonyms

Should we have both [gog-galaxy-2.0](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gog-galaxy-2.0) and [gog-galaxy](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gog-galaxy)? The latter has more uses and the former only has 2.

Answer (score 2):

From what I can tell, Gog Galaxy and Gog Galaxy 2.0 are separate... launchers?

Seems like Gog supports [Galaxy 2.0](https://www.gog.com/galaxy) still, with the first iteration being [loosely available](https://www.gog.com/forum/general_beta_gog_galaxy_2.0/where_to_download_old_version) if you know where to look.

Tags shouldn't be removed simply because one tag is used more over the other.  There could be users of both the original Galaxy and Galaxy 2.0, so leaving the tags alone is the appropriate thing to do.

Comment: Thanks! I guess once we confirm the differences, we should note them in the tag wikis.